# How can I turn off AGC when recording voice using AudioKit on iOS

Tags: swift, audio, audiokit

So I'm using AudioKit to record the microphone and some voice from users.
It's a wrapper on top of `NodeRecorder`. Nothing fancy, basically started from the recorder inside the CookBook app they provide.

However, I need to get more raw data from the microphone where I can whisper and yell.
The recording apply some equalizing and after some research, it seems to be  automatic gain control (AGC) being responsible.
However, I have no clue on how to deactivate it with AudioKit.
I'm seeing
[voiceProcessingAGCEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioinputnode/3152102-voiceprocessingagcenabled?language=objc) which is enabled by default. But the node inside `NodeRecorder` is a mixer and not an `AVAudioInputNode`.

Also saw some answers saying that I could use an EQFilter where I set the gain to 0 with a center frequency of 1000Hz. This is however not working in my case.

Do you have any idea how I could configure `AudioKit` and `NodeRecorder` so I don't get equalisers on voice?